# C - Resize/enlarge image

Tags: c, resize

I just want to say that I'm a novice at C. Alright, with that out of the way, my assignment over Christmas break has been to make a program that manipulates a PNG image in various ways. I've done most of the things, but I've run into a problem when trying to write the program that is supposed to enlarge the image. I have tried and I've gotten *something* down. Though I'm pretty sure it's all wrong...

```
    void enlargeImage(Image plain, char *imageInput[])
{

Image tempImage;
Pixel** pixels;

int scale = 2;

pixels = malloc(plain.height * sizeof(Pixel*) *scale);

for (int i = 0; i < plain.height; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = malloc(plain.width * sizeof(Pixel*) * scale);
}

tempImage.pixels = pixels;
tempImage.height = plain.height * scale; //Can I even do this?? Or is it completely wrong? 
tempImage.width = plain.width * scale;

// I've tried a few variations of this code 
for (int height = 0; height < plain.height; height++)
{

    for (int width = 0; width < plain.width; width++)
    {

            tempImage.pixels[height][width] = plain.pixels[height][width];

    }
} 



writeImage(imageInput, &tempImage); //This is a function written by my teachers. This is also where I get an error. I'm suspecting it's because I've doubled the size of tempImage ?? 

free(tempImage.pixels);
}
```

I'd be super grateful if someone could help me ^^
Thank you!

Comment: Memory allocation of your new scaled image looks correct. The assignment of pixels though in the loop is wrong. You're iterating in the old size, and setting just the original image pixels in the scaled one. You have to implement a mechanism to interpolate the original values into the new scaled image positions. Since scale is 2 for example, you could do that for every second pixel of a row of the image

Comment: I'm sorry, but we answer questions about *specific* programming issues.  Test your program.  If it in fact misbehaves then make your best effort to figure out the problem yourself before bringing that particular misbehavior to us.

Comment: @GregK. Oh, alright. Thank you C:

Comment: @GregK. "Memory allocation of your new scaled image looks correct." Are you sure? I don't think neither of `malloc()` are correct: both of them seems allocating too much memory for me. (supposing that `sizeof(Pixel) < sizeof(Pixel*)`) I don't think there should be `* (sizeof(char)*scale)` for the first `malloc()` and I think `sizeof(Pixel*) * (sizeof(char) * scale)` in the second `malloc()` should be `sizeof(Pixel) * scale`. (Note: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, so multiplying it isn't harmful, but I don't think it should be used here in order to make the meaning of allocation clear)

Comment: @GregK. Ah, the first `malloc()` isn't wrong. `sizeof(char)` is harmful for understanding program but not harmful for execution and `* scale` is needed because this program is doing image scaling. Using `sizeof(Pixel*)` for second `malloc()` still doesn't seem proper.

Comment: Calculating `tempImage.height` and `tempImage.width` before allocating memory for new image should be good than doing the pair of multiplications twice. Also do not forget to avoid out-of-range access and using indeterminate values in uninitialized buffer allocated via `malloc()`: use proper conversion of coords between source and destination images.

Answer (score 2):

1. The allocation should be like this:

```
tempImage.height = plain.height * scale;
tempImage.width = plain.width * scale;

pixels = malloc(tempImage.height * sizeof(Pixel*));
if (pixels == NULL) return;

for (int i = 0; i < tempImage.height; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = malloc(tempImage.width * sizeof(Pixel));
    if (pixels[i] == NULL)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) free(pixels[j]);
        free(pixels);
        return;
    }
}

tempImage.pixels = pixels;
```

Points are:

- Avoid doing pair of multiplications twice by calculating `tempImage.height` and `tempImage.width` before doing allocation.
- Though `sizeof(char)` is defined to 1 and therefore multiplying it isn't harmful, it seems producing confusion and making reading the program harder.
- The type of elements of `pixels[i]` is `Pixel`. so `sizeof(Pixel)` should be multiplied instead of `sizeof(Pixel*)` in the second `malloc()`.
- Allocate memory for all of the rows. Your program was allocating for only the first half of rows.
- Return values of `malloc()` should be checked in order to avoid dereferencing `NULL`, which is returned from `malloc()` when it fails, and invoking *undefined behavior*.

2. The conversion should be like this:

```
for (int height = 0; height < tempImage.height; height++)
{
    for (int width = 0; width < tempImage.width; width++)
    {
        tempImage.pixels[height][width] = plain.pixels[height / scale][width / scale];
    }
}
```

Points are:

- Set values for all pixels of the destination image (`tempImage`). Initial values of buffer allocated via `malloc()` is indeterminate and using them will invoke *undefined behavior*.
- Be careful not to access (no read nor write) out-of-range of arrays, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

3. You are freeing the list of rows by `free(tempImage.pixels);`, but you should free the data of each rows by adding

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempImage.height; i++)
{
    free(tempImage.pixels[i]);
}
```

just *before* the line `free(tempImage.pixels);`.
Note that `tempImage.pixels` and `pixels` are pointing at the same array, so you don't have to (and must not) use `free()` for both of them: use `free()` for only one of them.

4. Not knowing the actual signature of `writeImage`, convination of

```
void enlargeImage(Image plain, char *imageInput[])
```

and

```
writeImage(imageInput, &tempImage);
```

looks strange. Are you sure the first argument of `writeImage` should be a pointer to pointer to characters, not a pointer to characters like `char *imageInput`?

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the help and for explaining every step. I learned a lot of things my collage professor never even mentioned in class. As for the argument in 'writeImage' I think it should be? As I mentioned in my code above, it's a function written by my professors that I called (??) in my 'int main()' and then in my own written functions. AKA there are 3 different c files involved (I hope that made any sense).